# Переход с Python 2.6 на Python 3.7: has_key или in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Случилась необходимость переписать код на Python 3. Находил информацию о том, что has_key больше не используется с переходом к Python 3 и следует использовать in.

Сама задача состоит в поиске данных о местоположении слов, введенных пользователем,  в документах из определенной директории.
В переменной base_name хранятся ключевые слова из .dat файла, dict_in - словарь для слов, введенных пользователем, которые и предстоит искать в документах.

Привожу кусок кода:

```
    base_name = "shelt"
    dict_in = {}
    dict_out = {}
    c = []
    #создал множество из имен всех документов
    for file_name in os.listdir(dir_path):
        filename = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        c.append(filename)
    c = set(c)
    d = shelve.open(base_name)
    #составил массив из  введенных слов
    for i in input_values:
        if i in d is True:
            dict_in[i] = d[i]
```

Проблема начинается со строки с условием.

Попытки вывести содержимое dict_in (в целях проверки) ничем не увенчались - интерпретатор как будто не замечает строки с условием.

Однако дальше по коду он при намеренном вводе ошибки в код указывает на ее наличие (дальше по коду должны выводиться "строка, номер начальной позиции, номер конечной позиции" положения слова в документе (документах)).

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

UPD: предполагаю, что проблема в кодировке файла, с которого считываю данные (utf-8, расширение dat)

Comment: Как минимум `is True` уберите

Comment: @andreymal, убирал, но, к сожалению, все равно не проходит по этому условию

Comment: А что в d находится? А в input_values?

Comment: @gil9red, в d записываю данные с dat файла (внутри него были другим скриптом записаны слова и их местоположение (строка, начало, конец) в файлах - где какое слово находится).input_values -- разделенные split() строка из слов, введенных пользователем с клавиатуры (эти слова и предстоит искать в документах с помощью файла base_name)

Comment: Не, я про то, чтобы вам вывести содержимое этих переменных и не гадать почему не работает

Comment: @gil9red, d выводит <shelve.DbfilenameShelf object at 0x000000F6DE3123C8>, input_values - строку ['word', 'word'] - это проверял. Но пустым выводится dict_in -- массив, в который должны добавляться слова. которые найдены в base_name

Comment: Ну по `<shelve.DbfilenameShelf object at 0x000000F6DE3123C8>` непонятно, а что выведет print(dict(d)) ?

Comment: @gil9re, просто словарь - очень много текста, сократил popitem().
('РјСѓ', [[0, 25, 29, 'C:/Users/1/Desktop/project/project/docs/doc1'], [0, 25, 29, 'C:/Users/1/Desktop/project/project/docs/doc2']])
Где абракадабра, похоже, само слово - и так, похоже. со всеми словами из документов, которые я обработал другим скриптом. Похоже, что их надо как-то декодировать? Не подскажете, как именно? Буду благодарен:)

Comment: А попробуйте кстати открыть этот файл на питоне2 и посмотреть что там печатается. По идеи, латинские буквы не будут кракозябрами. Я с shelve не работал, поэтому не знаю. Если скинете тот файл могу попробовать поиграться с ним.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос решился сам собой: при использовании вместо имени

```
d = shelve.open("/Users/user/...directory path/shelvebasename")
```

полный путь до файла с shelve базой, то все работает. Остальные изменения Python3 по сравнению с Python2 ни при чем. Всем спасибо за ответы!